# ChangeTrustNotAllowed Error

Tags: horizon

I'm trying to run a Change Trust operation in order to add a trustline, but it throws me a ChangeTrustNotAllowed error which I can't reference in the [documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#change-trust).

Here's my [Transaction Envelope](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAJQ8YCVmD7CrwMmGcOQ%2FFQWPuDebKSAp5W1uYYfT50ycAAAAZADx67sAAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAACUPGAlZg%2Bwq8DJhnDkPxUFj7g3mykgKeVtbmGH0%2BdMnAAAAAYAAAABVFBDAAAAAACUPGAlZg%2Bwq8DJhnDkPxUFj7g3mykgKeVtbmGH0%2BdMnAAAAOjUpRAAAAAAAAAAAAHT50ycAAAAQPJySuC%2FirIdn7HI4GM4MHVBKojyDODpGy7S3fO0SiDI6IdJO64tSb%2FhKqTdnaJeu8%2B7PvUD%2FcASj4ZtkA15NAo%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope) and the [Transaction Result](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAAAAAGT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAG%2F%2F%2F%2F%2BwAAAAA%3D&type=TransactionResult).

I attach the error message:

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details. Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "instance": "horizon-001a/Fm1q5QnVH4-156771048",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAJQ8YCVmD7CrwMmGcOQ/FQWPuDebKSAp5W1uYYfT50ycAAAAZADx67sAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAACUPGAlZg+wq8DJhnDkPxUFj7g3mykgKeVtbmGH0+dMnAAAAAYAAAABVFBDAAAAAACUPGAlZg+wq8DJhnDkPxUFj7g3mykgKeVtbmGH0+dMnAAAAOjUpRAAAAAAAAAAAAHT50ycAAAAQOl23ijxXLlony2S+/trxM27gG1Dw7CfHPpQrzt/etor41+FYm+oO4+/W7WcRWTRfZpZkgLwkmfl7srLsjDGFg8=",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_failed",
      "operations": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAG////+wAAAAA="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a circular trustline, `sourceAccount` and `issuer` are the same.

A trustline can only be established from one account to another. Try creating one more account and set up the trustline between them.

Comment: I would agree, except I get this same error when trying to transfer an asset that is restricted by the issuing account with the `AuthRequiredFlag`.

Comment: @Derek True, the error may be caused by the account authentication settings. However, in this particular case Brian provided the link to the transaction envelope. If you check the XDR, you'll see that the problem was caused by the "circular" trustline.